# Share Class/Methods Between Windows Forms Application and Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, console

I have a solution that contains both a Windows Forms application and a Console application.
I have some functionality in the Windows Forms application that I would like to use in the Console application without manually copying and pasting the code into a second location.

Is there anyway to access a class/methods in the Windows Forms application from a Console application?  Or would I need to extract the functionality into its own .dll and reference that from both projects...

Comment: Yes, create a standalone class library for the shared code.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "ASP.NET" and such. That's what the tags are for. Besides, this question had nothing to do with ASP.NET.

Comment: The correct way to do this is to extract the common functionality into a class library and reference that library from the applications.

Comment: David, by class library do you mean a .dll?

Comment: @Baxter, yes a class library can be a dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Console Project
...Properties    
...Refernces <including CommonCode Class Library>
...Program.cs
...class1.cs
...etc
CommonCode Class Library
...classA.cs
...classB.cs
...etc




Winforms Project
...Properties
...Refernces <including CommonCode Class Library>
...Form1    
...Program.cs
CommonCode Class Library
...classA.cs
...classB.cs
...etc
```

i.e. both use the same common code project in their solutions, and both reference the project. Alternatively, if you are already happy with the common code. Compile it as a separate solutions (c claas library) and then reference the dll in both. Both end up the same thing - a dll in the bin folder.